# How can I draw vectors in octave?

Tags: vector, plot, octave

I want to make a program that adds two vectors and plots them together with their addition. But they have to be position vectors.

I tried creating `v1=[0;2]` and `v2=[1;3]` but displaying them with `plot` results in a number of scattered points.

How can I specify the starting position of the vectors, *e.g.* make `v1` and `v2` start from the origin?

Comment: "they are all over the place" is a rather imprecise description. Please post a [mcve] including your code, the resulting plot, and your desired results.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do what you are describing with the `quiver` function, whose purpose is to draw vector fields. Your example could be drawn with

```
   xx=[0;2];
   yy=[0;0];
   quiver(xx,yy,[0;1],[2;3],0,"linewidth",4);axis equal;xlim([-4 4]);ylim([0 5]);grid on;
```

It produces the following output:

[image]

The starting points of the vectors are specified by the two variables `xx` and `yy` in the following way: the starting point of the `n-th` vector is given by `[xx(n,1);yy(n,1)]` (look at `help meshgrid` for information on that. Basically, meshgrids are just a way to define the domain of a function, which here happens to be a vector field).

Comment: This is useful for, as you said, vector field, but not for bare vectors (like drawing vectors exactly as they are). Vectors in vector fields get scaled (their magnitudes get scaled) and their "visual length" does not reflect their actual length, and OP wants to demonstrate vector addition, so this is not suitable solution. (Consider case: `quiver([0], [0], [5], [4])` vs `quiver([0; 0], [0; 0], [5; 2], [4; 3]);` and look how vector  [5; 4] get scaled down, when you add another vector ([2;3]) as an argument to quiver).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of drawing math vectors in Octave:

```
clf
xs=[0 0 1 5 0]
ys=[0 0 7 1 0]
xe=[5 1 5 1 6]
ye=[1 7 1 7 8]
q=1;
h=quiver(xs(q),ys(q),xe(q),ye(q), 0,'b');
hold on
set (h, "maxheadsize", 0.033);
q=3;
h=quiver(xs(q),ys(q),xe(q),ye(q), 0,'--b');
set (h, "maxheadsize", 0.033);
q=2;
h=quiver(xs(q),ys(q),xe(q),ye(q), 0,'r');
set (h, "maxheadsize", 0.033);
q=4;
h=quiver(xs(q),ys(q),xe(q),ye(q), 0,'--r');
set (h, "maxheadsize", 0.033);
q=5;
h=quiver(xs(q),ys(q),xe(q),ye(q), 0,'g');
set (h, "maxheadsize", 0.033);
axis("square")
grid on
hold off
```